# Steam curl login - get cookie + sessionid (Multiple requests?)

Tags: php, curl, steam

I'm currently trying to get my sessionid and cookie from steam login.

When I login manually and check the network responses, I can see the info I need. It's located mainly in the **dologin/**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0YjG.jpg - First image is **getrsakey/** and the second image is **dologin/**

On the second image I marked what I need with a red box. I think I just need the **browserid** and **steamMachineAuth**.

```
$url = "https://steamcommunity.com/login/getrsakey/";
$params = ['username' => "MyUsername", 'password' => "MyPassword"];

$cookie_jar = tempnam('/tmp', 'cookie');

$session = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_jar);

$response = curl_exec($session);
die(var_dump($cookie_jar));
curl_close($session);
```

With the curl above, it seems like I only get **getrsakey/** stats for obvious reasons. I tried making a second curl request with the cookiejar I made, and then request **dologin/** but all I'm getting back is

`"{"success":false}bool(true)}"`

TLDR: I need the **browserid** and **steamMachineAuth** from the **dologin/** - See link above (Second image) basically the whole cookie if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is some time after question was added, but i think someone might still need an answer.

As You said, You need to make second request **dologin/** but not with the cookiejar You made.

First of all when You send request to **getrsakey/** You need only **username** parameter (password is not needed).

Than in response You get rsa key which You need to encrypt Your password using RSA method (key is divided into **key modulus** and **key exponent**).

RSA encrypted password needs to be encoded with **base64** and that is the **password** parameter You send to **dologin/**

But unfortunately STEAM might want to get Captcha code and/or SteamGuard code if account is protected, so You need to implement that as well.

I don't have working PHP code, but You may look into SteamBot writen in C# and write Your code based on it. Search for **Dologin** method in `SteamWeb.cs` file:
https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamBot/blob/master/SteamTrade/SteamWeb.cs#L88